# How to make several selections for search with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, select, search

Hello Symfony experts !

I have a question. I'd like to know if it's possible to build a search bar with have several forms.

I am building a website where I want to show events. I would like to make a search available by location (city and country) and by type of event.

I already built the three entities : City, Country and Categories (Type of events). I entered the categories, cities and countries in which the events will take place in the database. I would like users to have access to a selection to make their choice.

How is it possible to do it ? Do you have some documentation about it ?

Thank very much. :)

Comment: Are you sure you need several forms for your search bar ? If so, which fields each form would have ? Don't you need instead one form with 3 fields that allow to select a City, Country or Category ?

Comment: @NicolasAppriou, probably yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you actually have 3 form types: one for each of your City, Country and Category.

Now you, need another form type used to filter your events. So you need a fourth form type (lets name this one `EventFilter`) with three fields to select your filter elements.
Selecting entities can be done with an [EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

Your form should look something like:

```php
class EventFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, ['class' => Country::class, 'required' => false])
            ->add('city', EntityType::class, ['class' => City:class, 'required' => false])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, ['class' => Category::class, 'required' => false]);
    }
}
```

You use it as every form in your controller

```php
    public function showEvents(Request $request): Response
    {
        $form->createForm(EventFilterType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // Something like ['country' => null, 'city' => City, ...]
            $data = $form->getData();
        }
    }
```

### One step futher

I you want to have your code extra clean, you should write a class to handle your form data:

```
class EventFilter {
    public function __construct(
        public ?Country $country = null,
        public ?City $city = null,
        public ?Category $category = null,
    ) {}
}
```

This allows you to add proper validation. For example, if `$city` and `$country` are set, check if the city is in the country.

In the controller, you will get an `EventFilter` instance when calling `$form->getData()`.
You can event set some initial value more easily:

```php
    public function showEvents(Request $request): Response
    {
        $filter = new EventFilter(
            category: $this->getUser()?->getPreferedCategory(),
        );
        $form->createForm(EventFilterType::class, $filter);

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Hello Nicolas Appriou. Thank you for your answer. I have to say I am facing with many errors... One of them is : An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType": The required option "class" is missing.

Comment: Yes. The EntityType need a [class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage) option to tell which entity you want to use. The example code was written to give you an idea, I did not build a symfony project to check it. With this, you have the basic idea, you need to adapt it to your need.
I added the class option, but you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I found my error. Thank you for your help Nicolas.

Comment: Hello Nicolas. I have a question about the "One step futher" part, does it help to get setted values when we go back to the form ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "go back to the form" ? What type of "help" are you expecting ?

Comment: Hello Nicolas. I asked you my question in order to answer this ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790695/how-to-retrieve-values-set-previously-in-a-form-symfony-6-0-2/73798047#73798047. Thank you very much for helping. Have a good day ! ;-)