# How to retrieve values set previously in a form ? Symfony 6.0.2

Tags: forms, symfony

I made a search form in order to let user choose the city and category (for events). When I land on events.html.twig, I get to right informations. :)

Now, what I'm trying to do is when I go back to the search form, I'd like to keep the values I set last time in the form. I want retrieve them when I go back to the search form so that when I want to change only one thing, I can. ^^

I tried some solution (it's in the comments) by opening a session in order to keep the values entered in the form. At the moment, I am lost in my code. I don't know how I can do it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{   
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request)
    {   
        /* $session = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession(); */        
        /* $session->set($data); */
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class/* , $data */);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            /* $session->set($data); */
            return $this->render('front/events.html.twig', $data);
        }

        return $this->render('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(/* $data */)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making several errors. First of all, when you need to read or write something in Session you need to specify a key:

```
$session->set('search-data', $data);
$data = $session->get('search-data');
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html for more information about the Session component.

Regarding your task, you need the following steps:

1. Check if there is any search data in Session (`$data = $session->get('search-data')`)
2. Pass that data to the Form (`$this->createForm(SearchType::class, $data )`)
3. If the form is valid than you can save the data in Session (`$session->set('search-data', $data);`)

When you render the form, you do not need to pass again $data (which is already inside the form). Use this:

```
return $this->renderForm('view_name.twig', [
     'form' => $form,
]);
```

and see https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html for more information about the Symfony Form.

Comment: Thank you Luigi. I had an error, so I added this : $entityManagerInterface->persist($data); And now, I have an other error that comes from this new line : EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.

Comment: Should I create a new class ? ...because $entityManagerInterface->persist(); doesn't accept $data.

Comment: The EntityManager is for persisting Entities to Database. You do not need the EntityManager in this context.

Comment: Oh, I see... I created a new ticket to figure out this error.